# Globalizing date & time format in MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, localization, utc

we are following MVC pattern, which is best place for converting toUTC and toLocal in controller or in javascript? Also whether we need to save the date format in invariant culture to support globalization? (or) is there any standard thumb rule/best practice for globalizing date time formats in MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are benefits and drawbacks of each approach.

#### Server Side

- You'll need to know the user's time zone.  Usually this is done via user selection on some settings page within your app.  Once you know the time zone, conversions usually done with `TimeZoneInfo` or with [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), in your MVC controller.
- You'll need to know the user's culture (ex. `en-US` or `fr-FR`, etc.) to display the correct format (ex. `MM/dd/yyyy` vs `dd/MM/yyyy`).  This can be done via .NET globalization.  The formatting should be done in your MVC *view*, not the controller.
- You'll need to stay on top of time zone updates, as time zones rules can change as the governments of the world change their minds about their offsets and DST transition dates.

#### Client Side

- You'll send just the UTC time to the browser, and let it convert to whatever the local time zone is.  No need for the user to choose - as long as you only care about their current local time zone.
- Getting the formatting right can still be tricky.  Libraries like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) can help.
- There are [some bugs](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/06/07/javascript-date-type-is-horribly-broken/) that may or may not affect your conversions.  Be aware of them.

---

With regard to your question about the invariant culture - you would need to elaborate on what you mean by "save the date".  If you mean storing to a database, such as SQL Server, the culture and format are irrelevant.  Send a `DateTime` to your database, not a string.

Comment: I will explain with example I have server in "mm/dd/YYYY" date format and web page opened in Australia with date format as "dd/MM/YYYY" If I save a record to database on 4th June 2015 in client format will be 04/06/2015, but when this date is saved in sql the format will be as 06/04/2015. So is this the correct way to store date format in sql db ?

Comment: SQL doesn't store dates as strings, so your question doesn't make any sense. Store and pass date values using their correct data types and format will never enter the picture.