# How to use Jquery globalization package for date validation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, globalization, unobtrusive-validation

I'm having problems with my jquery date validation script so I installed the jquery globlization package.I'm very new to packages and installation of packages so I'm not quite sure how to utilize the scripts. I tried doing the following but it still gives me this error.

[image: Enrollment]

[image: Globalization]

Everything in the Scripts folder
[image: Scripts]

Snippet in Views\User\Create.cshtml

```
   <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
    { %>
       <%: Html.ValidationSummary(false) %>
       <%: Html.EditorForModel() %>
        <p> <input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
            <% } %>

    </fieldset>
}
```

Views\User\Create.cshtml

```
@model RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>User</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstMidName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstMidName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstMidName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
        </div>

    <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
    { %>
       <%: Html.ValidationSummary(false) %>
       <%: Html.EditorForModel() %>
        <p> <input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
            <% } %>

    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917036/globalizing-date-time-format-in-mvc

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add en-NZ into this line of code found in jquery-ui-1.8.24.js and the date validation started to work

```
$.extend(this._defaults, this.regional['']);


$.extend(this._defaults, this.regional['en-NZ']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DT_Project_Start, "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}")
```

and see if it works